# Netcat to send/receive to/from DPDK is not receiving forwarded packets

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, netcat, dpdk

I'm running the DPDK Skeleton example, which forwards received packets:

https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/skeleton.html

```
sudo ./dpdk-skeleton -l 1 -n 4
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 4
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_e1000_igb (8086:1533) device: 0000:05:00.0 (socket -1)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_e1000_igb (8086:1533) device: 0000:0a:00.0 (socket -1)
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Port 0 MAC: 98 b7 85 00 5b 87
Port 1 MAC: 6c b3 11 52 a3 29

Core 1 forwarding packets. [Ctrl+C to quit]
```

It is running on these ports:

```
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    110208   6549/./dpdk-skeleto  /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     108476   6549/./dpdk-skeleto  /var/run/dpdk/rte/dpdk_telemetry.v2
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM      CONNECTED     110213   6549/./dpdk-skeleto
```

So in one terminal I am using netcat to generate traffic to port 108476:

```
nc -l -p 108476 < /dev/random
```

and in a second terminal I am listening on port 110213 for DPDK to forward the data:

```
nc -l 110213
```

However, the second `netcat` command (listening) is not outputting anything. DPDK should be forwarding packets.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The number you gave does not seem to be port number. A port number is like the `22` in `tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN 879673/sshd`. The line needs to have both `tcp` and `LISTEN`. But seeing your output of `netstat`, it seems dpdk-skeleton is not using tcp socket, but unix socket.

Comment: @Philippe does that mean it's not possible to use `netcat` here?

Answer (score 1):

`/var/run/dpdk/rte/dpdk_telemetry.v2` seems to be the unix domain socket.

You can first install `socat` with :

```
apt-get install socat
```

and try :

```
date | socat - /var/run/dpdk/rte/dpdk_telemetry.v2
```

then check if `dpdk-skeleton` prints anything.

I cannot install dpdk, so cannot test.

Comment: Thanks Phillippe, I will give this a try and report back. I also read the DPDK Cookbook and they discuss using trex to generate packets. Would this achieve the same as dpdk_telemetry.v2?